# client_backend vs parallel_worker?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
```

And it shows 2 rows with same query content (under `query` field), and in `active` state,

but one row show `client_backed` (`backend_type`) and the other row show `parallel_worker` (`backend_type`)

1. why do I have 2 instances of same query ? (I have run just one query in my app)
2. what is the different between `client_backed` and `parallel_worker` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL v10 there is [parallel processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html) for queries:

If the optimizer decides it is a good idea and there are enough resources, PostgreSQL will start *parallel worker* processes that execute the query together with your client backend. Eventually, the client backend will gather all the information from the parallel workers and finish query processing.

This speeds up query processing, but uses more resources on the database server.
The parameters that govern this are, among others `max_parallel_workers`, which limits the total limit for parallel worker processes, and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, which limits the numbers of parallel workers for a single query.